# How to see the mime type of a file?

Tags: pantheon-files, files, mimetype

Nautilus has the option to see the mime-type of a file.

Can I see that in elementary OS without Nautilus?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Pantheon Files:

Right click on a file, Properties:

[image]

---

The above may give a different result than `file --mime-type`, so maybe this one is also useful.

To add an option for that in the context menu of the file manager:

Installing gedit as text editor:

```
sudo apt-get install gedit
```

Installing Gnome Terminal for the option to hold terminal open:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-terminal
```

Open gnome-terminal, Edit - Profiles, create new profile called 'hold'

[image]

Edit, and under ' Title and command' - When command exists - ***Hold the terminal open***.

[image]

In Terminal:

```
sudo gedit /usr/share/contractor/show_mimetype.contract
```

Paste this:

```
[Contractor Entry]
Name=Show mime-type
Icon=/usr/share/icons/elementary/apps/128/application-default-icon.svg
MimeType=application/octet-stream;application/binary
Exec=gnome-terminal --profile hold -e 'file --mime-type -b  %f'
```

Save.

[image]

Comment: Correct me if I was wrong, I have `MimeType` as an option in properties without nautilus

Comment: @Ravan - I do too. See the beginning of the answer. But it took me some time to see that so I shared it here.

Comment: Hey +1, got it now :) silly me =)

Comment: @Ravan - you are right implying that the rest of my answer is possibly useless. It also gives a different result (more generic) but maybe for that very reason it may be useful in some cases.